# Better encapsulation technique

Tags: php, oop, encapsulation

I have this class:

```
class Mail
{
    private $content;
    private $from;
    private $to;
    private $subject;

    public function __construct($content, $from, $to, $subject)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
        $this->from = $from;
        $this->to = $to;
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }
}
```

At some point i would like to send a mail object. The content might be styled with html + css, there might be other modifications before sending. There are various mail providers i can use. What option would be better:

```
class Mail
{
    // ...

    public function mail(MailProvider $provider)
    {
        $provider->send($content, $subject, $to, $from);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
$mail = new Mail(/* Parameters */);
$mail->send(new Mailjet());
```

Or simply add getters to Mail class and then do:

```
$mail = new Mail(/* Parameters */);
$mailProvider = new Mailjet();
$mailProvider->send($mail->getContent(), $mail->getFrom /* etc */);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about other messages? What if you would like to send a content and a subject as a text?

As a guiding principle for oop, I try to use [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).  It provides 5 guiding principles to help create maintainable code.

The principles help to promote the thought of "how is the application likely to change, and when it does change, what code will need to change", with the goal of changing as little as possible, and having as little cognitive load, as possible, necessary to perform the change.

In general the first option seems like an unnecessary coupling.  A mail object needs to understand how to use a provider? Is that strictly necessary?  To add a provider, we may have to change the `Mail` objects `mail` method. (ie if the provider `send` needs additional parameters.

Whereas the second option, removes 1 degree of coupling, and only requires that the provider can operate on a message.  Adding a message field, or having the provider send method, is less likely to require a change to mail.

Which option makes it as easy as possible on the client (the client can be yourself :))  Subjectively, I think that the second option does as it allows for a "mail" team to work independent of an integration team, and only requires that the mailjet team know that they will be receiving a "mail" interface, if that makes any sense at all...

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself: What is the responsibility of each object? Then the answer becomes somewhat self evident.

- `Mail`: **represents** a mail message (emphasis on *represents*)
- `Mailjet`: contains code specific to communicating with external service

From this description neither class should hold the code to *send* mail. What you probably want is a third class:

- `MailSender`: takes a `Mail` and sends it using a specific service

Roughly sketched:

```
interface Mail {
    public function getContent();
    ...
}

interface MailServiceAdapter {
    public function send($content, $from, ...);
}

interface MailSender {
    public function send(Mail $mail);
}

class MailSenderImplementation implements MailSender {
    public function __construct(MailServiceAdapter $adapter) { ... }
    ...
}
```